# Registry hive parse

Tags: python, registry

I am trying to parse some registry hives (SAM, Software, System) for forensic analysis from a forensic image (.E01) format. I am wondering if that is possible using Python. With a few searches I found some implementations with Regipy, but will it work with extracted hives ?

I am not very familiar with Python so, is it possible to write a script and getting as input a registry hive in order to print the details and the contents of it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parse registry hives for forensic analysis using the python-registry library.  Are you bound to Regipy because there are other python libraries you can use.  Here is an example of some simple code.  First you need to install Python-registry but then could use this to grab the contents of the hive.

```
try:
    from Registry import Registry
except ImportError:
    print("[!] Python-Registry not found")

# Load the SYSTEM hive
hive = registry.Registry.open("SYSTEM")

# loop through the hive and print the names of all the keys
for key in hive.root_key().subkeys():
    print(key.name())
```